How to display multiple images in Cinema4d using a python plugin
I am iterating over an asset list which contains the images that I want to render in each row along with the text
The code is
            for i in range(0, 4):
                    asset = assets_list[i]
                    asset_tags = asset['image_tags']
                    asset_image = asset['image'][0]
                    status = asset['iterations'][0]['status']
                    if asset_tags:
                        if self.GroupBegin(10000 + i, c4d.BFH_SCALEFIT, cols=3, rows=1):
                            self.GroupBorderSpace(10, 5, 10, 5)
                            
                            self.AddUserArea(7000 + i, c4d.BFH_CENTER, initw=50, inith=50)
                            image_area = ImageArea(asset_image, f'asset_{i}.png')
                            
                            self.AttachUserArea(image_area, 7000 + i)
                            self.LayoutChanged(7000 + i)
                            
                            # image_area.Redraw()
                            
                            print(f"Attached image area for asset {i}: {image_area}")

                            self.AddStaticText(1000 + i, c4d.BFH_CENTER, name=asset_tags[0])
                            self.AddButton(2000 + i, c4d.BFH_CENTER, initw=100, name="Import Asset")
                            self.GroupEnd()
                self.GroupEnd()

and the code for Image area is
class ImageArea(gui.GeUserArea):
    def __init__(self, image_url, image_name):
        super().__init__()
        self.image_url = image_url
        self.image = bitmaps.BaseBitmap()
        self.image_path = self.download_image(self.image_url, image_name)
        self.setImage(self.image_path)
        self.Redraw()

    def download_image(self, url, image_name):
        try:
            tmp_file = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), os.path.basename(image_name))
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, tmp_file)
            print(f"Downloaded image to: {tmp_file}")
            return tmp_file
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to download image: {e}")
            return None
        
    def setImage(self, path):
        if os.path.exists(path):
            result = self.image.InitWith(path)
            if result[0] != c4d.IMAGERESULT_OK:
                print(f"Image initialization failed with error code: {result}")
                self.image = None
            else:
                print(f"Image initialized successfully from {path}")
                self.LayoutChanged()
        else:
            print(f"Image file does not exist at: {path}")
            self.image = None

    def DrawMsg(self, x1, y1, x2, y2, msg):
        print("DrawMsg called")
        self.DrawSetPen(c4d.COLOR_BG)
        self.DrawRectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2)
        if self.image:
            width, height = self.image.GetSize()
            if width > 0 and height > 0:
                print(f"Drawing image with dimensions: {width}x{height}")
                self.DrawBitmap(self.image, x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1, 0, 0, width, height, c4d.BMP_ALLOWALPHA)
            else:
                print("Image dimensions are zero.")
        else:
            print("No image to draw.")

    def GetMinSize(self):
        print("GetMinSize called")
        if self.image:
            width, height = self.image.GetSize()
            return min(width, 50), min(height, 50)
        return 50, 50

But the result is it is onlyable to render the last image of the asset list rest all of them are blank
the result in Cinema 4D
In logs I can see that DrawMsg is only called once at the last not with every image maybe that's why only the last image is visiable and I don't know how it works internally
I tried to update the layout using LayoutChanged function and called it explicitly for each userArea
I just want to render all the images in each row seperatly
